# Triangular factorization with pivoting Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm new to Octave and Matlab and I have a problem. I need to make a program, which solves a Triangular system of linear equations and making a triangular factorization with pivoting. [image]

For example I need to do next exercise

[image]

That is my lufact function

```
function X = lufact (A, B)

[N, N] = size(A);
X = zeros(N, 1);
Y = zeros(N, 1);
C = zeros(1, N);
R = 1:N;
for p=1:N-1
  [max1,j]=max(abs(A(p:N,p)));
  C = A(p, :);
  A(p, :) = A(j + p - 1, :);
  A(j + p - 1, :) = C;
  d = R(p);
  R(p) = R(j + p - 1);
  R(j + p - 1) = d;
  if A(p,p) == 0
   'A is singular. No unique solution'
    break
  endif
endfor

for k = p + 1: N
  mult = A(k,p)/A(p,p);
  A(k,p) = mult;
  A(k, p + 1: N) = A(k, p + 1: N) - mult*A(p, p+1: N);
endfor
endfunction

Y(1) = B(R(1));
for k = 2: N
  Y(k) = B(R(k)) - A(k, 1:k - 1)*Y(1:k - 1);
endfor

X(N) = Y(N)/A(N,N);
for k = N-1: -1: 1
  X(k) = (Y(k) - A(k, k + 1: N)*X(k + 1: N))/A(k, k);
endfor
```

And that is my main function

```
A = [2 4 -6; 1 5 3; 1 3 2];
BA = [-4; 10; 5]
BB = [20; 49; 32]
XA = lufact(A, BA);
XB = lufact(A, BB);
disp(XA);
disp(XB);
```

The output of my program

[image]

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to fix that?

Comment: Are you really asking the full [Chapter 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666436/matlab-triangular-system-of-linear-equations) of your homework on SO? See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be attempting to answer the question you're asking, so your question doesn't make much sense...

But, in any case. The exercise asks you to show that ***given*** the following matrices / vectors:

```
A = [ 2, 4, -6;    1, 5, 3;    1,   3, 2 ];
L = [ 1, 0,  0;  1/2, 1, 0;  1/2, 1/3, 1 ];
U = [ 2, 4, -6;    0, 3, 6;    0,   0, 3 ];
```

show that `LY = B, UX = Y, AX = B` for a given `B`.

Ok. In octave, the best way to solve a matrix equation of the form `aX = b` w.r.t X for a given `a` and `b`, is to use the "matrix left-division" operator, `\`, i.e. `x = a\b`. Type `help mldivide` in your octave console for details.

So,

```
Y = L\B;
X = U\Y;
A*X   % the result should be the same as B. QED.
```

---

Then there is the separate question of how can I perform LU decomposition in octave? Well, octave provides a function for this: `lu`.

```
[L, U] = lu(A)
% L = 1.0000        0        0
%     0.5000   1.0000        0
%     0.5000   0.3333   1.0000
%
% U = 2   4  -6                                                                                                           
%     0   3   6                                                                                                           
%     0   0   3
```

---

Then there's the implied further question of "I would like to perform LU decomposition by hand."

Great. Good luck. Your code here is a bit messy, no comments, no self-explanatory variable names ... I won't attempt to debug it here in detail. One thing to note though is, LU decomposition only takes a matrix as an input. I'm not sure why you are trying to pass the 'B' matrix to it as an input. Plus it doesn't seem like you're using it anywhere in the function. Or creating L or U matrices for that matter. Also, if the whole top part is inside an `lufact.m` file, then you should know that your function terminates well before the for loops; these get ignored completely. What were you trying to do exactly?